# Javascript 404 Resource Not Found NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio

I'm running a Node JS server on an old laptop of mine, and I've portforwarded the port 8006 so that I can connect to the node server from another computer and view the web pages. However, I have a sound file that I want the server to play when something happens, but after checking the console output on my computer, it keeps throwing this error:

> GET http://0.0.0.0:8006/surprise.mp3 404 (Not Found)

Where of course the zeroes are my actual IP address (the ip of the server). Everything else runs fine including all the javascript files and the webpages. This is the code that actually plays the sound:

```
var audio = new Audio('surpise.mp3');
audio.play();
```

And that's sitting inside one of the client-side javascript files. How can I make that particular mp3 file accessible to outside users?

Comment: Did you create a node.js route that serves the MP3 file?  A node.js server doesn't serve any files by default.

Comment: What should I send back as the response then? I'm assuming I should route a GET for /suprise.mp3, I just don't know how to send over the mp3 file.

Comment: If you're using Express, then you just use `res.sendFile("/somepath/surprise.mp3")`.

Comment: Ok I'll try that out. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the Express framework (which it sounds like you are), you can create a `.get()` route for `/surprise.mp3` and then use `res.SendFile("/somepath/surprise.mp3")` so that your node.js server will serve that file when that route is requested.

Or, if you have multiple static files to serve, you can use [`express.static()`](http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html) to set up a directory of static files that will get automatically served.

Comment: I did that but I'm getting a strange url encoded error. Btw, I'm also using body parser. And with the express.static() I setup my directory with "app.use(express.static(__dirname));" Will that do the trick?

Comment: @ScottyPippen - you never want to do  `app.use(express.static(__dirname));` because that serves your server code files.  You should serve static files out of some other directory that ONLY contains files you want served.

Comment: Then should I get rid of that code and instead setup a route for the base url get that returns index.html so that the webpage can be seen?

Comment: @ScottyPippen - If your files are static, then `express.static()` works great.  Just put them in a different directory than your code files are and point `express.static()` at that other directory.